# How to use If Not Exist with Derived table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some output If no records return my select statement I set some default values else will return actual values. I tried below script I got an error

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                         ClientName AS Client, LoadMonth, 
                         RecordCount AS No_Valid_Indicator_Count
                     FROM 
                         DBA.dbo.UnifiedDatabaseSummary 
                     WHERE 
                         ClientName = 'XXXXX' 
                         AND LoadMonth = (SELECT MAX(LoadMonth) 
                                          FROM DBA.dbo.UnifiedDatabaseSummary 
                                          WHERE ClientName = 'XXXXX')
                         AND ItemValue = 'NonICD09or10' 
                         AND Item = 'TotalClaims'))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        'XXXXX' AS Client, 201509 AS LoadMonth,
        0 AS No_Valid_Indicator_Count
END
ELSE
    SELECT
        ClientName AS Client, LoadMonth, 
        RecordCount AS No_Valid_Indicator_Count
    FROM
        DBA.dbo.UnifiedDatabaseSummary 
    WHERE 
        ClientName = 'XXXXX' 
        AND LoadMonth = (SELECT MAX(LoadMonth) 
                         FROM DBA.dbo.UnifiedDatabaseSummary 
                         WHERE ClientName = 'XXXXX')
        AND ItemValue = 'NonICD09or10' 
        AND Item = 'TotalClaims') T8
```

Error :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `select` on top of `If not exists` just remove it and put the result in temp table. Like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT clientname  AS Client, 
                      loadmonth, 
                      recordcount AS No_Valid_Indicator_Count 
               FROM   dba.dbo.unifieddatabasesummary 
               WHERE  clientname = 'XXXXX' 
                      AND loadmonth = (SELECT Max(loadmonth) 
                                       FROM   dba.dbo.unifieddatabasesummary 
                                       WHERE  clientname = 'XXXXX') 
                      AND itemvalue = 'NonICD09or10' 
                      AND item = 'TotalClaims') 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT 'XXXXX' AS Client, 
             201509  AS LoadMonth, 
             0       AS No_Valid_Indicator_Count into #temp
  END 
ELSE 
  SELECT clientname  AS Client, 
         loadmonth, 
         recordcount AS No_Valid_Indicator_Count into #temp
  FROM   dba.dbo.unifieddatabasesummary 
  WHERE  clientname = 'XXXXX' 
         AND loadmonth = (SELECT Max(loadmonth) 
                          FROM   dba.dbo.unifieddatabasesummary 
                          WHERE  clientname = 'XXXXX') 
         AND itemvalue = 'NonICD09or10' 
         AND item = 'TotalClaims' 

Select * from #temp Inner join ..
```

Comment: I have to inner join this output to other table that's why I used derived table concept

Comment: @Dinesh - add the result to temp table

Comment: Create a table variable or temp table and populate it.

Comment: But I'm using More than 10 Inner join to fetch final output in one row. In this case how to use temp table and table variable

Comment: @Dinesh Add the temp table as 11th inner join to your existing join's nothing will break. Already i have shown you how to add the result to temp table. Now you just need to add the temp to your joins

Comment: @MM93 & @ Dan Bracuk - Thanks.

Is there any other method available for this scenario?